# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync in ApiController does not trigger events

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class that downloads files that works in a console application and now I want to use it in a webapi project.

To download a file I use

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
bool downloadFinished = false;

wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    ProgressChanged(e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive, e.ProgressPercentage);
};
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    downloadFinished = true;
};

wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fileUrl), Path.Combine(DOWNLOADFOLDERTEMP, FileName));

while (!downloadFinished)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

Which works in a console program, but not inside an ApiController.
It downloads the file, but the progress and completed events never trigger, resulting in an endless loop.

How do I make WebClient trigger events when called in an ApiController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebClient` uses the current `SynchronizationContext` to posts its events into. You are not releasing the current thread by busy-waiting. I don't know why you are performing the download asynchronously and then waiting for the result. What good does this do? Just use the synchronous API.

At least, do not spin-wait. Use WebAPI's support for async to IO to get rid of the waiting loop. Use async and await. You'll find on the web how to do that with `WebClient`.

Your use of `downloadFinished` is not thread-safe. But you shouldn't need such a variable anyway.

Comment: WebClients synchronous DownloadFile does not report progress, that's why I am using DownloadFileAsync.

Comment: @elch OK, that makes sense. Then get rid of the polling loop and use an event or better yet await with a TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: If you use an event you'll have the same deadlock issue. You can suppress the sync context while calling WebClient to solve that. With await you won't have any issue like that, but async code is invasive.

Comment: I am using DownloadFileTaskAsync now. Changed all methods to be async and await when needed.